# Align equation in Latex with isotope notation and unit

Tags: math-mode

I need to write this long equation in two lines, which comes with an isotope notation and units. this is what I did so far:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{aastex6}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apj}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyref}
\usepackage{ulem} %RTF: for strike-through in resubmission
\usepackage{color} %RTF : For color in resubmission
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\dot{E_{\gamma}} = \frac{M${}^{56}$Ni}{M_{\odot}}\Bigg[7.78A_{\gamma}(Ni)e^{-t/8.76d}+
1.50A_{\gamma}(Co)\Big[e^{-t/111.27d}-e^{-t/8.76d}\Big]\Bigg]10^{43}
\end{equation}
erg/s
\end{equation}
```

here I am getting error with the ${}^{56}$Ni part inside the equation environment and also the equation is too long and needs to be divided into two lines. Your suggestion is most appreciated.

Comment: Inside an `equation` you are already in math-mode, so you should not use `$ ... $`.

Comment: but then the Ni isotope comes in italic and not as plain text, how do I resolve this?

Comment: There might be better ways, but `\mathrm{Ni}` comes to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from using `$ .. $` when you're already in math mode (in the `equation` environment). To set the isotope in roman font, use `\mathrm`, or `\ce` from the `mhchem` package (see second example in code below).

The `amsmath` package has several environments for multi-line displayed math, so have a look at the manual. In this case `multline` is appropriate I think.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{aastex6}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apj}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} %% added
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyref}
\usepackage{ulem} %RTF: for strike-through in resubmission
\usepackage{color} %RTF : For color in resubmission
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
\dot{E_{\gamma}} = \frac{M{}^{56}\mathrm{Ni}}{M_{\odot}}\Bigg[7.78A_{\gamma}(\mathrm{Ni})e^{-t/8.76d} \\
+1.50A_{\gamma}(\mathrm{Co})\Big[e^{-t/111.27d}-e^{-t/8.76d}\Big]\Bigg]10^{43}
\end{multline}

With mhchem-syntax:
\begin{multline}
\dot{E_{\gamma}} = \frac{M\ce{^{56}Ni}}{M_{\odot}}\Bigg[7.78A_{\gamma}(\ce{Ni})e^{-t/8.76d} \\
+1.50A_{\gamma}(\mathrm{Co})\Big[e^{-t/111.27d}-e^{-t/8.76d}\Big]\Bigg]10^{43}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```